# Recent apache + mod_wsgi + django install instructions?

Tags: apache-2.2, django, mod-wsgi

I've been hunting 'round google and the web to get a django setup running with apache and mod_wsgi under ubuntu 10.04, but with no success.

Does anyone know of any recent instructions on how to install the aforementioned products?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [stock instructions](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/IntegrationWithDjango) worked for me.